# Error 9 VBA form populate different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a form that will open up on sheet1 where users can type in all the information .
I would like the information to populate on sheet8 however its giving me an error can anyone help.
I'm getting a subscript out of range error.

Thanks in advance!

```
Private Sub EnterInfo_Click()

    Dim LastRow As Range
    Dim DataTable As ListObject


    'Add row to bottom of Data table
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Data").ListRows.Add

    'Enter data from form into our new row
    Set DataTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Data")
    Set LastRow = DataTable.ListRows(DataTable.ListRows.Count).Range

    With LastRow

        .Cells(1, 1) = StaffName.Value
        .Cells(1, 5) = ClientName.Value
        .Cells(1, 4) = Month.Value
        .Cells(1, 7) = Description.Value
        .Cells(1, 6) = Hours.Value

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a Table named as Data exist in your activesheet?

Comment: Sixthsense

Sheet1 is "EmployeeInput"
Sheet8 is "EmployeeData"

Comment: Still you are missing my point.  In your code it tries to get data from Data Table from the Activesheet.  This line "ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Data").ListRows.Add".  So check is there any table named as Data is exist in that activesheet.

Comment: How do i know which is the active sheet? There is a Table labeled  "Data" on sheet8

Comment: Then change this line "ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Data").ListRows.Add" to Sheets("sheet8").ListObjects("Data").ListRows.Add

Comment: Oh you are amazing thank you so much !!!

Comment: @Sixthsense, can you add that as a proper answer?

Comment: Yes, now I added it.

Answer (score 0):

> How do i know which is the active sheet? There is a Table labeled
>   "Data" on sheet8 – Leofig123

Then change this line

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Data").ListRows.Add
```

To

```
Sheets("sheet8").ListObjects("Data").ListRows.Add
```